# Loading tablecell content from custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-view, tablecell

I am new to `swift` and below is the problem that I face
I have a tableview and one of the cell is customCell which loads custom view. No crashes but the constraints and background color for table cell are not displaying. **Please refer to code below**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {


    let data = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape"]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var customView: CustomView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customView.myLabel.text = "Hey hey"
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell()}

//            cell.layoutSubviews()
//            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }


    }
}


Custom View:
class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    let kCONTENT_XIB_NAME = "CustomView"
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, owner: self, options: nil)
        contentView.fixInView(self)
    }

}

extension UIView
{
    func fixInView(_ container: UIView!) -> Void{
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        self.frame = container.frame;
        container.addSubview(self);
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}

Custom Tablecell:
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellContentView: CustomView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        cellContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Below is the storyboard structure 
[image]

When I run the app below is the screenshot how it displays
[image]

**Issue 1**: Row 3 is customview whose background should be blue as set in Custom cell class

**Issue 2**: In my viewcontroller, even after setting background color as green why is it not displaying that color. "Orange" is used in storyboard while creating view

**Issue 3**: If I have more dynamic controls in view, how the cell height be set.

Please advice. I'm struck here

Answer (score 0):

For **Issue 1** , You have to add custom view as cell's content view. Just add following line:

```
contentView.addSubview(cellContentView)
cellContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```